# Unable to connect to Aurora MySql using .net core application deployed on Aws Ecs

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have an application in .net core 3.1 and I am using MySql with that. To connect to MySql I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql nuget.

My .net core application is deployed as a docker container on AWS ECS and I am using Aurora MySql RDS to store data. I have granted "Publicly accessible" access to the Aurora MySql and I can connect to the db using MySql workbench and also with my .net core application using localhost. But when I deploy the application and try to perform any db action then it starts giving throwing exception:

> An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient
>   failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding
>   'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.

Then I have added retry pattern like this:

```
 services.AddDbContextPool<DataContext>(options =>
      options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), builder =>
      {
          builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), null);
      }
  );
```

and my connection string is something like this:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=db-cluster-1-instance-1.cqb2fsjwx78p.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Database=dbName;User ID=admin;Password=password;port=3306"
```

After adding retry pattern. I am getting this error:

> "Maximum number of retries (5) exceeded while executing database
>   operations with 'MySqlRetryingExecutionStrategy'. See inner exception
>   for the most recent failure."

So I suspect, it's something else. What am I doing wrong here? Or it might be something wrong at aws side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was related to docker image I was pulling.
I was using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1`. Changing it to `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic` worked.
https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/222

Comment: Had the same issue and this fixed it. Excelent find! I would have had no idea it was related to the docker image...

Answer (score 0):

Add `SslMode=None` to your connection string and see if the connection works (see [MySqlConnector's Connection String Options](https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/)). The transient exception just means, that Pomelo (i.e. MySqlConnector) was unable to connect to the database server.

So this is related to connection problems (either fixable by altering the connection string or by changing your Aurora/firewall configuration).